# Disposing contents of StdOut

Tags: c#, ubuntu, .net-core

I am writing an application to manage processes and handle failovers. This program is written in C# for .NET Core and will run on Ubuntu Server 16.04 x64.

I have this code to create processes and track them, with exit events and such

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    WorkingDirectory = "/home/xyzserver/someprocess",
    FileName = "mono",
    Arguments = "someprocess.exe",
    RedirectStandardOutput = true
};

_proc = Process.Start(psi);
_proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
_proc.Exited += ProcOnExited;
```

I understand from the docs [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput(v=vs.110).aspx) that calls to `Console.WriteLine` will block if the `_proc.StandardOutput` stream is full. I want to prevent this behavior and dispose all the output from the managed application, since it will also write to a physical log on its own.

In addition, I would like to avoid storing any of the output in any unused stream buffers since they will never be used. A preferred solution will not `UseShellExecute`.

I have considered adding these 2 lines in the hope that any received data will be disposed, but am unsure about correctness.

```
_proc.OutputDataReceived += (sender, eventArgs) => {};
_proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
```

Is there a better way to accomplish this? Thoughts or comments are appreciated.

Comment: As said in linked article, you may filter you data and avoid writing to the output for console. This is what you did - you simply ignore the incoming data. Did you face any issue with it? Did you try without any data handlers?

Comment: @VMAtm I tried the async approach mentioned in the article (OutputDataReceived above) - I created a program to output text rapidly and ran it for a few minutes without any issues. However, I also noticed that the RAM usage of the application increased by many MBs, so I'm afraid that even when I dispose of it, the runtime might be storing it somewhere. As for the synchronous solution, I'm not entirely sure how to test if it hangs on `WriteLine`, so I didn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manually ran the test on .NET Core using 3 programs:

1. An HTTP server to track the *TextOutputter* program.
2. A TextOutputter program that prints 1000 characters and makes an HTTP request every second.
3. a ProgramRunner that runs one instance of TextOutputter.

Without the 2 lines, the buffer fills upto 64k and stalls. With the 2 lines, there is no stalling.